# Pass data from CollectionView to TabBarController, than to his childs in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I am new to Swift. Unable to find solution for below problem. 
Below is a  ViewController with CollectionView and When you click on Cell in CollectionView, data from cell(even this who isn't in label and image view, but are in Book array row) must be send to TabBarCollection, than from TabBarCollection I need to send this data to all of child's, like in this image. 
Later in childs of TabBar I will set value of Labels in View Controllers from data from choosed Cell. 
[image]

Book.swift

```
import UIKit

struct Book {
    let title: String
    let image: UIImage?
    //Here soon will be more "let", and this data will also have to be send to TabBar but it don't will be show I CollectionViewCell
}

extension Book {

    static let books: [Book] = [
    Book(title: "Antygona", image: UIImage(named: "imgantygona")!),
    //etc
    ]
}
```

CollectionViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var bookImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bookTitle: UILabel!

    func setup(with book: Book) {
        bookTitle.text = book.title
        bookImageView.image = book.image
    }
}
```

ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let books = Book.books

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)]
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(fontAttributes, for: .normal)

        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self      

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return books.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "bookCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        let book = books[indexPath.item]
        cell.setup(with: book)

        return cell
    }
}
```

I saw many solutions but I can't perfectly adapt it to my problem. :( 
Thanks for help !

BookInsideViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class BookInsideViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var testImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use collection view DidSelectItemAt function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourtabbarIdentifier") as! UITabBarController

// You should access the `imageController` through your `tabBarController`, 
// not instantiate it from storyboard.
if let viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers, 
   let imageController = viewControllers.first as? ImageController {
    BookInsideViewController.recivedData1 = Books[indexPath.row]
}

navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBarController, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I set storyboard ID in TabBar to "bookTabBar", than replace it on "YourtabbarIdentifier" but now I have problem 
"Use of undeclared type "ImageController" and unresolved identifier "Books", I don't know how to do this what you said "You should access the `imageController` through your `tabBarController`, not instantiate it from storyboard." Can you please explain me how to do this? Thank you for help :)